# "NameError: name 'day_time' is not defined" error in Python3.8

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, nameerror

I am making a program which tells the part of the day by the time entered.

My code:

```
user_day = input("What's the time? ")

if user_day >= 20 and user_day <= 24:
    day_time = "Night"

elif user_day >= 24 and user_day <= 12:
    day_time = "Morning"

elif user_day >= 12 and user_day >= 17:
    day_time = "Noon"

elif user_day >= 17 and user_day >= 20:
    day_time = "Evening"
```

But I am getting this error:

```
if day_time == 1 and user_weather == plus:
NameError: name 'day_time' is not defined
```

Please help me out.

Comment: where is this errored code relative to the ```if user_day...``` part of the code?

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare `day_time` outside the context of if blocks if you wish to use it later on.

Like so, for example:

```
user_day = input("What's the time? ")

day_time = None

if user_day >= 20 and user_day <= 24:
    day_time = "Night"

elif user_day >= 24 and user_day <= 12:
    day_time = "Morning"

elif user_day >= 12 and user_day >= 17:
    day_time = "Noon"

elif user_day >= 17 and user_day >= 20:
    day_time = "Evening"
```

Answer (score 1):

- The issue is, `user_day` is a string when entered as an input.

  - Because it's a string, it doesn't meet any of the conditions, and therefore, `day_time` remains undefined.

    - Wrap the input in a `try-except` block to check that the input is a proper data type. In this case, `str` type that can be converted to an `int` or `float`.
  - It must be converted to a `int` or `float` depending on if you're going to accept only hours or fractional hours.
- `user_day` should be in a `while True` loop to continue asking for a time until a valid numeric input is received.
- Finally, the code can be written more efficiently, by properly ordering the conditions from smallest to largest, for this case.

  - `user_day` will trickle down to the correct condition.

```py
while True:
    try:
        user_day = int(input("What's the hour on a 24-hour scale? "))
    except ValueError:  # checks for the correct data type; maybe someone will spell the hour
        print('Please enter the hour as a numeric value')
    
    if (user_day >= 24) or (user_day < 0):  # 24 and over or less than 0 are invalid times
        print('Please enter a valid time')
    else:
        break  # break when there's valid input

if user_day < 12:
    day_time = 'Morning'
elif user_day < 17:
    day_time = 'Noon'
elif user_day < 20:
    day_time = 'Evening'
else:
    day_time = 'Night'
    
print(day_time)
```

### Use [`np.digitize`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html)

- Return the indices of the bins to which each input value belongs.
- Use the value returned by `np.digitize` to index the correct value from `day_time`

```py
import numpy as np

while True:
    try:
        user_day = int(input("What's the hour on a 24-hour scale? "))
    except ValueError:  # checks for the correct data type; maybe someone will spell the hour
        print('Please enter the hour as a numeric value')
    
    if (user_day >= 24) or (user_day < 0):  # 24 and over or less than 0 are invalid times
        print('Please enter a valid time')
    else:
        break  # break when there's valid input

day_time = ['Morning', 'Evening', 'Noon', 'Night']
idx = np.digitize(user_day, bins=[12, 17, 20])
    
print(day_time[idx])
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `day_time` in an `else` statement so that when neither of the existing conditions meet, `day_time` will still have a value.

Also, you need to convert the user's input into an integer before you can use the `<`, `>`, etc operator on it with a string:

```
user_day = int(input("What's the time? "))

if user_day >= 20 and user_day <= 24:
    day_time = "Night"

elif user_day >= 24 and user_day <= 12:
    day_time = "Morning"

elif user_day >= 12 and user_day >= 17:
    day_time = "Noon"

elif user_day >= 17 and user_day >= 20:
    day_time = "Evening"

else:
    day_time = "Unknown"
```